# gevent redis too many connection file

Tags: redis, gevent

I use gevent and redis, and I found the memory is so high(6G) with time going on. I use lsof -p to debug the question, and found there are so many socket file are opened. I use redis connection pool, why so many socket file is opened.

Comment: how many connections you keep open at the same time and how many connections do you see from lsof?

Comment: I don't limit the connection number, and shouldn't it automatically closed? I see more than 10000 connections from lsof